# how to target class with multiple text fields using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am generating text fields via php.
So, depending on the user, it could output 1 text field, 3 text fields, 5 text fields, however many.
In each of those text fields I want to perform an ajax search.
Each text field will search exactly the same database table.
I have managed to give each ID of the text field a number starting at 1 and then it goes up to however many text fields there are.
The issue is the CSS.
I tried to use a class to style the search results but if I type into not text field, results start showing in ALL text fields instead of just the one I am typing into.

This is the code for the text fields outputted in the loop:

```
<?php
echo "<input id='search{$item}'  name='search[]'type='text' autocomplete='off' onKeyUp='ajax_call(\"{$item}\")'>";
echo "<div style='display:none' id='loading{$item}'><img src='functions/loading.gif'/></div>";
echo "<ul class='test'></ul>";
```

Here is the jQuery and Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#loading").hide();

function ajax_call(textfield) {
    var textfield_value = textfield;
    $("#loading" + textfield_value).show();
    var search = $('#search' + textfield_value).val();
    if (search.length > 3) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'functions/daily-prod/lost-time-search.php',
            data: {
                search: search
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    $('.test').html(data);
                    $("#loading" + textfield_value).hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    if (search.length < 1) {
        $('.test').html('');
        $("#loading" + textfield_value).hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.test {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.test li {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -39px;
    color: #000000;
}

.test li:hover {
    background: #dddddd;
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Generated HTML code is:

```
   <input id='search1' name='search[]'type='text' autocomplete='off' onKeyUp='ajax_call("1")'>
   <div style='display:none' id='loading1'><img src='functions/loading.gif'/>  </div>
   <ul class='test'></ul><input id='search2'  name='search[]'type='text' autocomplete='off' onKeyUp='ajax_call("2")'><div style='display:none' id='loading2'>
   <img src='functions/loading.gif'/></div><ul class='test'></ul><input id='search3'  name='search[]'type='text' autocomplete='off' onKeyUp='ajax_call("3")'>
   <div style='display:none' id='loading3'><img src='functions/loading.gif'/> </div><ul class='test'></ul>
```

Comment: Could you also post the generated html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `<ul class="test></ul>` an `id` attribute `test{$item}` and adjust the function call to use `$('#test' + textfield_value)` like you have done with the input fields.

```js
$("#loading").hide();

function ajax_call(textfield) {
  var textfield_value = textfield;
  $("#loading" + textfield_value).show();
  var search = $('#search' + textfield_value).val();
  if (search.length > 3)
    $('#test' + textfield_value).html("<li>" + search + "</li>");

  if (search.length < 1) {
    $('#test' + textfield_value).html('');
    $("#loading" + textfield_value).hide();
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.test li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -39px;
  color: #000000;
}

.test li:hover {
  background: #dddddd;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='search1' name='search[]' type='text' autocomplete='off' onKeyUp='ajax_call(1)'>
<div style='display:none' id='loading1'><img src='functions/loading.gif' /></div>
<ul id="test1" class='test'></ul>

<input id='search2' name='search[]' type='text' autocomplete='off' onKeyUp='ajax_call(2)'>
<div style='display:none' id='loading2'><img src='functions/loading.gif' /></div>
<ul id="test2" class='test'></ul>
```

Comment: @ K Scandrett, you are a 

legend!

Comment: Just out of interest. Is it okay to use the method I am using with the ID's or is there a better way to do it without using ID's? I can ask another question if necessary. Just wondering if this method is okay

Comment: There are many ways to approach the task, but what you're doing is fine in my book.